Problem 237 "Mathematical Quickies:270 Stimulating Problems with Solutions" Particle Movement
I was solving "Mathematical Quickies:270 Stimulating Problems with Solutions" when I came across a very peculiar question (Problem 237):
A particle moves in a straight line starting from rest and finishing at rest covering unit distance in unit time. Prove that the magnitude of its acceleration at some point must be at least $4$ units (assuming that there is no abrupt change in velocity and acceleration i.e. they are continuous functions).
Converting this into more familiar mathematical notation, suppose $f(t)$ (the distance as a function of time) is a twice continuously differentiable function satisfying $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$. Prove that there exists some $c$ such that $|f''(c)| \geq 4$ where $c \in (0,1).$
My attempt:
Applying LMVT, there is some $b \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(b)=1$. Again, applying LMVT on $f'(x)$ in $(0,b)$ and $(b,1)$, $f''(c_1)=\dfrac{1}{b},f''(c_2)=\dfrac{1}{b-1}$ where $c_1 \in (0,b),c_2 \in (b,1)$. Applying Rolle's theorem, I can also write there exists some $c_3 \in (0,1)$ such that $f''(c_3)=0$. But none of this brings me closer to solving the problem at hand. How do I make further progress?
The solution in the book uses a rough sketch of the $v-t$ plot and the fact that the area it encloses must be equal to the area of the isosceles triangle of altitude $2$ and base $1$. The claim is that the $v-t$ curve will always either coincide or exceed this isosceles triangle at some point (which appeals to visual intuition) thereby having a slope more than or equal to $\pm 4$. Still, I'm trying to construct a more mathematically rigorous explanation. Can anyone help me?

SORRY about the completely unrelated title, I mixed up two questions, thank you very much @Prem

No worries , I did guess what had occurred. Such things happen.

Either $|\frac1b|\geq2$ or $|\frac1{b-1}|\geq2.$

Here’s another rigorous explanation that doesn’t require thinking about triangles.
Assume that the acceleration is at less than $4$ always.
Repeatedly integrating and using that $f’(0)=0$, we have that $|f’’(t)|< 4$, so $|f’(t)|=|f’(t)-f’(0)|< 4t$, so $|f(t)-f(0)|< 2t^2$ for positive $t$. At $t=1/2$, this gives $|f(1/2)-f(0)| < 1/2$.
A symmetric argument using $f’(1)=0$ gives $|f(1)-f(1/2)| < 1/2$. Adding the two gives that $|f(1)—f(0)| \leq |f(1)-f(1/2)|+|f(1/2)-f(0)|< 1$ thus the particle moved less than one unit.
Thus, if the acceleration is always less than $4$, then the particle must move less than $1$ in total over that time. The contrapositive gives your desired result.

Here's a more mathematically rigorous explanation of what the solution is saying:
Suppose there exists a path $f(t)$ such that $f'(t)$ does not exceed the bounds of this isosceles triangle (whose path is given by $f_0(t)$). Then it follows that $f'(t) \le f_0'(t)$ for all $0 \le t \le 1$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
1 = \int_0^1 f'(t) \ \mathrm{d}t \le \int_0^1 f_0'(t) \ \mathrm{d}t = 1
\end{align*}
and so we must in fact have equality. Hence, either $f$ cannot be contained inside $f_0$.
Now suppose $f \neq f_0$, so $f$ exceeds $f_0$, suppose at time $T$ i.e. $f'(T) > f_0'(T)$. Then either $0 \le T \le \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2} \le T \le 1$. In the former case, the average acceleration from $t = 0$ till $t = T$ must exceed $4$. Similarly in the latter case, the average acceleration from $t = T$ till $t = 1$ must be below $-4$.
Hence, we conclude that the acceleration must at least magnitude $4$ at some point.
